# IndexOfName of an Object

Tags: c#, arrays, list, object, indexof

I am trying to create a `List<Object>`, `Object` means complex object, however, if I want to do `ObjectCollection.Item["A"]`, I will get the A item from the list.

But I am not sure how to archive this.

Comment: I fixed the formatting of your question and still have no idea what you're asking. Please elaborate.

Comment: Try looking up the "Dictionary" collection type.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create `extension` method.

Sample:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public static class Extension
{
    public static Foo Item(this List<Foo> list, string item)
    {
        return list.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == item);
    }
}
```

Get an item from list,

```
Foo selectedFoo=bar.Item("C");
Console.WriteLine(selectedFoo.ID + " " + selectedFoo.Name);
```